# preventing variable expansion in makefile

Tags: shell, makefile

I want to write this into a file:

```
-MF"$(@:%.o=%.d)" -MT"$(@)" -o "$@" "$<"
```

but when I echo this into a file, with `""`, or `''`, the variables will expand, how can I prevent the expansion and write it as is?

P.S. `echo '-MF"$(@:%.o=%.d)" -MT"$(@)" -o "$@" "$<"'` is called in a makefile.

in my makefile, I let's say I have:

```
all:
    echo '-MF"$(@:%.o=%.d)" -MT"$(@)" -o "$@" "$<"' > $file
```

what I see in the file is

> -MF"all" -MT"all" -o "all" ""

Comment: Single quotes won't expand do parameter expansion, did you try `echo '-MF"$(@:%.o=%.d)" -MT"$(@)" -o "$@" "$<"' > file`

Comment: I did, it does expand them

Comment: @Inian: I am running this in a makefile,

Comment: That's a key piece of information in this question's context. Do update the same

Comment: Might be useful to show the resultant expansion in your question

Comment: Please post the entire recipe.  Single `$`'s are expanded in makefile context -- you can use `$$` to represent a `$` in the recipe/bash context.  Also add a makefile tag to the question

Comment: You likely need to escape the special characters that are expanded as variables

Comment: Usually preceding the special character with one or more slashes \ does the trick.

Comment: I have used \ before the $, it doesn't work. still expands

Comment: @John : adding $$ instead of $ solved the problem, thanks man

Comment: bash is not involved in make expansion **at all**; the tag bash should not be present in this question. (`/bin/sh` will be passed the results of prior expansions run by `make`, but `/bin/sh` is not guaranteed to be `bash` -- and even when it is, it's bash-running-in-compatibility mode).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `$$` to put a dollar sign into a Makefile recipe

```
all:
    echo '-MF"$$(@:%.o=%.d)" -MT"$$(@)" -o "$$@" "$$<"' > $file
```

Comment: that is so random and unlike any other escaping mechanism in shell...